# How to simulate Heroku react app build locally?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, heroku

I have a Rails/React application that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku. I'm getting errors while trying to build the React app because its looking for `@types/*` that are in my `devDependencies` but shouldn't be. I can fix this by moving them to the `dependencies` section of my `package.json` file but I'm wondering why I'm not getting these errors when I run the `yarn build` or `yarn heroku-postbuild` scripts locally. I imagine that maybe I've got a setting somewhere locally that I don't have on Heroku where I'm building a developer build or something that isn't catching these errors.

How can I simulate the React build on Heroku locally so I'm not getting surprised by these errors when I try to deploy?

Here's the relevant pieces of my `/package.json` file:

```json
"engines": {
  "yarn": "1.22.5",
  "npm": "6.14.4",
  "node": "10.19.0"
},
"scripts": {
  "build": "cd client && yarn install && yarn build && cd ..",
  "deploy": "cp -a client/build/. public/",
  "heroku-postbuild": "yarn build && yarn deploy && echo 'Client Built'"
},
```

Here are the relevant(?) pieces of my `/client/package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev-start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "gen": "graphql-codegen --config codegen.yml"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This could help [Build your app and run it locally](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#build-your-app-and-run-it-locally)